Load a JSON file into a local HTML document without disabling CORS
I want to find a way to enable uploading a file to a game without having to use the --disable-web-security flag in Chrome.
I've got the following line of code in my HTML to let the user select a file to load into the game:
<input type="file" name="gameData" id="gameData"><button id="loadGame">Load Game</button>

The following javascript code is the current attempt to load the file and parse it, assigning each array accordingly...
    $("#loadGame").on("click", function() {
        var filePath = $("#gameData").val();
        $.getJSON(filePath, function(data) {
            round1Chain = data.round1Chain;
            consoleWrite(`Round 1: ${round1Chain}`);
            round2Chain = data.round2Chain;
            consoleWrite(`Round 2: ${round2Chain}`);
            round3Chain = data.round3Chain;
            consoleWrite(`Round 3: ${round3Chain}`);
            round4Chain = data.round4Chain;
            consoleWrite(`Round 4: ${round4Chain}`);

            speedChain1 = data.speedChain1;
            consoleWrite(`Speed 1: ${speedChain1}`);
            speedChain2 = data.speedChain2;
            consoleWrite(`Speed 2: ${speedChain2}`);
            speedChain3 = data.speedChain3;
            consoleWrite(`Speed 3: ${speedChain3}`);

            bonusChainA = data.bonusChainA;
            consoleWrite(`Bonus A: ${bonusChainA}`);
            bonusChainB = data.bonusChainB;
            consoleWrite(`Bonus B: ${bonusChainB}`);
            bonusChainC = data.bonusChainC;
            consoleWrite(`Bonus C: ${bonusChainC}`);
        });
        consoleWrite(`Game loaded.`);
    });

As expected, without disabling the security, I get the following error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/fakepath/20240829_1013.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

How can I allow the browser to parse the file so it can load the game information?  I want the game to be able to be run off my web server (once it's loaded) or locally, if one saves the game.  I don't yet want to package it in an electron container, but that will most likely happen down the road.  What can be done for the time being?  Currently the only workaround I've had is having a fixed line of code looking for "gamedata.js", and just replace the file in the directory with a js file containing all of the variables.  It works, but not quite as user-friendly as having the user upload an arbitrarily-named file that gets parsed on the fly.

You're trying to use HTTP to read your local file system.  If this is meant to be a web application then host it on a web server (even one running locally on the same workstation).  Pages loaded from file:// are very limited.

This is intended to be used both on and off of a web server.  That's why I want to get around the CORS limitation any way I can, so whether I use the file locally or connect to the internet, I'll be able to load and parse the file.  Seems I'd have to look into the File System API..

If the intent is for the user to supply a file, the page could accept the file from the input type="file" rather than try to read it directly from the file system.  It looks like the HTML already allows the user to supply a file, so I don't see why AJAX is needed here in the first place.
